# How can I add into List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> desc

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to add multiple items into this

Comment: Yes, it is possible. All controls have a `Visible` property.

Comment: Yes Sire. It is possible. That's all you wanted to ask really ?

Comment: i am a newbie to asp.net so when  i posted this q's so i dint know much about user controls so i posted this q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct response to that question: Yes, it is possible.

The indirect response:

`<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="This is a test"></asp:Label>`

```
//Check weather the condition matches
if("this" != "That")
{
    //If not, it will hide the label.
    lblTest.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: This can be a comment at the most.

Comment: At least*. He asked a question, and I postd an answer to it. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user controls can be hidden / shown conditionally. Here's a more complete example:

```
<uc1:UC1 ID="userControl1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<uc1:uc2 ID="userControl2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<uc1:uc3 ID="userControl3" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (something = "a")
            userControl1.Visible = true;
        else if (something = "b")
            userControl2.Visible = true;
        else
            userControl3.Visible = true;
    }
```